# Enforcing parameter value restrictions across components

Tags: javascript, angular, enums, interface

I have multiple components with parameters that I want to restrict to specific values. For example (in pseudo-code) :

```
class MyFirstComponent {
    @Input() myParameter: 'foo'|'bar'|'baz';
}

class MySecondComponent {
    @Input() myParameter: 'foo'|'bar'|'baz';
}
```

In both components, `@Input() myParameter` should only accept the same restricted values. Instead of copying the allowed values in each component I want to abstract the restrictions. How would I do this? I assume it would require `enums` or an `interface` but I do not know how to implement either approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type. Define it somewhere, maybe a separate file, and export it. This is more of a TypeScript than Angular thing.

```
export type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

Then import it in the file where you want to use it.

```
import {MyType} from './path/to/file'
```

And use the newly created type:

```
@Input() myParameter: MyType
```

Comment: MyPath? Where did that come from? :)

Comment: Guess it's a typo :) MyType should be there

Comment: Yeah, fixed. Sharp eyes!

Comment: I attempted your approach but when I tried `[myParameter]="'aksjdaksjdh'"` the component still accepted the value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It probably works in development mode because it's using JIT compilation, which doesn't do type checking. If you're using the Angular CLI, try running `ng build --prod` and it should fail, since it uses AOT. By the way, using a `type` like I did is nothing different than your original code in terms if type-checking. With your code, it would still work in JIT and should fail in AOT.